# Will installing VS2015 update 3 VC++ redistributables break other software

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, vcredist

As suggested in [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5e565499-b855-4300-83cd-46be2a126519/app-compiled-with-redistributable-140239180-crashes-on-machine-updated-to-redistributable?forum=vcgeneral), If I install the VC++ redistributables for VS2015 update 3 am I likely to break other software running on the same PC built with previous updates to VS2015?  Similarly, if I stick with update 2 for my release, is this going to get broken at some point in the future when someone installs the redists for update 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the bug description as reported at [New VC Runtime 14.0.24210.0 breaks MFC app built with VS 2015 Update 2](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2892501/new-vc-runtime-14-0-24210-0-breaks-mfc-app-built-with-vs-2015-update-2) the U3 redistributables will indeed break `MFC` apps compiled with U2 or earlier, which:

- use `MFC` in a DLL i.e. not statically linked, and
- create objects of type `CMFCToolBarButton` or derived.

From the linked page:

> The problem is caused by the new BOOL member m_bIsDragged in class CMFCToolBarButton.
>   So memory layout differs between Update 2 and 3.
>   When initializing m_bIsDragged in the constructor, the (stack) memory behind the ToolBarButton is overwritten.
>
> The problem should arise also on all classes which are derived from CMFCToolBarButton:
>
> CMFCColorMenuButton
>   CMFCCustomizeMenuButton
>   CMFCDropDownToolbarButton
>   CMFCOutlookBarPaneButton
>   CMFCRibbonGalleryMenuButton
>   CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton
>   CMFCToolBarDateTimeCtrl
>   CMFCToolBarEditBoxButton
>   CMFCToolBarFontComboBox
>   CMFCToolBarFontSizeComboBox
>   CMFCToolBarMenuButton
>   CMFCToolBarMenuButtonsButton
>   CMFCToolBarSpinEditBoxButton
>   CMFCToolBarSystemMenuButton

---

[ *EDIT* ] For completeness, it should be pointed out that apps that use AppLocal deployment of the `MFC/CRT` DLLs are not affected, since they do *not* use the system-wide installed copies thereof.

AppLocal deployment is described under bullet #6 "*updated September 11 2015*" in "*Distributing Software that uses the Universal CRT*" at [Introducing the Universal CRT](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/).

Comment: Thanks for this and the links.  We're statically linking MFC so hopefully shouldn't be a problem.